# Reading return values from Method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I have a method where in I am calling different method to get values.

```
public String processMe(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SomeException {
..
validate(request,Number,Date); 
//How do I read values here ..
//I would like to read Number and Date from validate??
..
}
```

validate method will be returning me some values from database.

```
private String[] validate(HttpServletRequest request,String Number,String Date) {
 ..
 //My logic which get me some values from database and returns
 ..
 values[0]=something;
 values[0]=somethingElse;
 ..
 return values;  //This is returning values..
 }
```

Comment: just update `processMe()` method return statement as  `return validate(request,Number,Date);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already return a string array. So add the Number, Date to the end of the array and assign the return value to a variable. Then you can access the Number and Date.

Ex: String[] validated = validate(request,Number,Date);

```
private String[] validate(HttpServletRequest request,String Number,String Date) {
 ..
 //Add the Number, Date to the array
 values[0]=Number;//array index can be anything you like(you can add them to the end of the array)
 values[1]=Date;
 ..
 return values;  //This is returning values..
 }
```

now you can access the array like this.

```
public String processMe(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SomeException {

    String[] values = validate(request,Number,Date);

    System.out.println(values[0]);//values[0] will contain the Number
    System.out.println(values[1]);//values[1] will contain the Date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Data transfer Object.
Create a ViewModel Class with all possible return values from your Method ,Create a instance of it and assign them values and return the instance of ViewModel.

Even Make your return type of Method to ViewModel Class

Example

```
Class ReturnValues
{
String value1,value2;
int Value3; //etc
}
```

And your Method will look like

```
 private ReturnValue validate(HttpServletRequest request,String Number,String Date) {
     ..
     //your logic which get me some values from database and returns
     ..
     ReturnValue rt=new ReturnValue();=
     rt.value1=something;
     rt.value2=somethingElse;
     ..
     return rt;  //This is returning values..
     }
```